# Copying when delimiter is variable

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a .txt file which has integers separated by spaces. My table is temp(a int, b int). My file has input like

```
1   918
...
9   12
10  17
...
99  87
100 12
```

Please note that the space between two integers depends on the "length" of the first integer, which is variable. How am I supposed to copy these to my table?

My try: (which is definitely wrong)

```
COPY temp FROM 'address/to/file' ( FORMAT TXT, DELIMITER(' ') );
```

I know there has to be more than just 1 space, but I don't know how am I supposed to do it. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a one time operation? If so maybe you could replace any multi spaces with a single space manually?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It's a homework actually. I can replace that in my dataset but the instructor's dataset will be different. It'll cause problem then

Answer (score 0):

Import the whole line into another temp table first, as a single field:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE x (t TEXT);
COPY x FROM 'C:\temp\1.txt'
```

`SELECT *` result:

```
t
-------
1   918
9   12
10  17
99  87
100 12
```

Then manipulate the data and put into your table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (a INTEGER, b INTEGER);

INSERT INTO t
SELECT r[1]::INTEGER, r[2]::INTEGER
FROM (
        SELECT REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY(t, '\s+') AS r
        FROM x
) AS rr
```

`SELECT *` result:

```
| a   | b   |
| --- | --- |
| 1   | 918 |
| 9   | 12  |
| 10  | 17  |
| 99  | 87  |
| 100 | 12  |
```

Comment: The size of the file is is about 400 mb. Inserting one by one would take a really long time while I'll have maximum 5 minutes to do all of my operations(that I've to do after inserting the values). It was a really nice idea by the way. Will keep in mind for later!